# Bootstrap mobile image zoomed in

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-4

The cover image on mobile is zoomed in way more than I want. The pictures below should show you what I mean.

[This is what it looks like in development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cur7w.png)

[This is how it looks on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv5e0.jpg)

```css
 html,
    body,
    .view {
      height: 1000px;
      background-attachment: fixed;
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    @media (max-width: 740px) {
      html,
      body,
      .view {
        height: 1000px;
      }
      a {
        font-size: 3.5vh;
        padding: 1.5vw;
      }
      .card {
        width:100%;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 850px) {
      html,
      body,
      .view {
        height: 600px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="view" style="background-image: url('https://wallpaperstream.com/wallpapers/full/space/Dark-Space-Wallpaper.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
               <div class="cover-container ph-auto h-100 row align-items-center" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="cover-inner container content col text-center text-primary">
                 <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Home</h1>
                 <p class="lead">Singing · Rapping · Screaming</p>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this id to your first div and delete the inline style

```
#background-image{
  background-image: url('https://wallpaperstream.com/wallpapers/full/space/Dark-Space-Wallpaper.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 85% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

first div

```
<div class="view" id="background-image">
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/r485f3vt/)

Comment: unfortunately i am still receiving the same results, if visited on mobile it is still zoomed in. https://sixfeetsleepmusic.com/

Comment: You want be always the whole image as background?

Comment: I want the picture to be fixed to the top, but on mobile it is zoomed in way more than on desktop. The problem is the second picture I posted, the first picture is what I am trying to achieve